# How to upgrade system node in nodenv?

Tags: node.js, npm, terminal, environment, iterm

I am using **nodenv** to manage my application's node versions.

Currently my `global` node is set to `system`.

```sh
$ nodenv global
system
$ node -v
v16.10.0
```

I've tried to set up `global` node to `v17.5.0` but previously installed global packages were, of course, not installed over.

How can I upgrade `system`, and thus `global`, to `v17.5.0` carrying over globally installed npm packages?

Comment: What operating system are you using? How did you originally install the system node?

Comment: Mac OS, I've installed it through nodenv. It sets system and global node that it has been installed while installing it.

Comment: By definition, the `system` node wasn't be installed using nodenv, since `system` means "The version of node that would be used if nodenv doesn't specify a different version". You probably installed it through Homebrew, MacPorts, or the nodes.org installer.

Comment: Thanks @MosheKatz, you are right, I've installed it through brew, I didn't remember it.
That said, do you think it's possible to upgrade system node through nodenv to that it automatically install globally installed packages as well or do I to re-install them manually? I've looked into nodenv documentation and I didn't find anything similar. 
Anyway, thanks again for your comments.

Comment: @caruso_g -- late reply, but you can't.  I put together a script with all my "npm -g xxxx" defaults that I run whenever I install a new version